# In Vi/Vim how to map current item variable (v:val) with a string?

Tags: vim, concatenation, vi

I'm trying to concatenate a string with range values in Vim using map function to no avail.

For example:

```
:for i in range(5) | put="No ".i | endfor
```

will output

```
No 0
No 1
No 2
No 3
No 4
```

but

```
:put=map(range(5), '"No" . v:val')
```

doesn't work. Is it possible to achieve the same result using a combination of `put+map+range` ?

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe "No" . v:val part could be used inside join function instead to achieve the same result?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to escape the quotes

```
:put=map(range(5), '\"No\" . v:val')
```

This is because `put` is **not** under `:h :quote`.

Comment: Thank you Matt. That was exactly the issue. Appreciated!